# styling visited links belonging to a class

Tags: css, hyperlink, css-selectors, visited

I cannot find a way to style `a:visited` but only those belonging to `.extern`.

`a:visited.extern` doesn't work and neither does `a.extern:visited` (I' using Mozilla Firefox 43.0.1 for Linux x86_64)

The reason is I have a small icon I'd like to add to `.extern` links, and I want to change its `url()` when the link is visited.

```
<style>
    a.extern {
        padding-right:1.3em;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: scroll;
        background-position: right center;
        background-clip: border-box;
        background-origin: padding-box;
        background-size: 0.7em 0.7em;
        background-image: url("img/link.png");
    }

    a:visited:extern {
        background-image:url("img/link-visited.png");
    }

    a.extern:visited {
        background-image:url("img/link-visited.png");
    }
</style>
```

In the end all **visited** links of this type should be affected

```
<a class="extern" href="http://etc.etc.etc">link</a>
```

Comment: use `a.extern:visited {`

Comment: use `<a class="extern" href="http://etc.etc.etc">link</a>`. Remove `.` in class in anchror tag

Comment: you are right,... it was my mistake in copyting the code to this post. in the actual code there is no `.` in front and still doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

Basically what you want to do is restricted by browsers, particularly Firefox.

[**Per MDN - Privacy and the :visited selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector)

> You will still be able to visually style visited links, but there are now limits on what styles you can use. Only the following properties can be applied to visited links:
>
> - color
> - background-color
> - border-color (and its sub-properties)
> - outline-color
> - The color parts of the fill and stroke properties

Comment: More importantly, it has nothing to do with the addition of a class selector.

Answer (score 2):

First, I assume the name of your class is `extern`, and not `.extern`, so your `a` tag will look something like this.

```
<a class="extern" href="http://etc.etc.etc">link</a>
```

To style only the visited links which have the extern class you should use:

```
a.extern:visited {
    background-image:url("img/link-visited.png");
}
```

Notice how the `:visited` selector is added at the end: `a.extern:visited`.

Comment: you are right about the class name: was my mistake in writing this question. However `a.extern:visited` seems not working on Mozilla Firefox 43.0.1 for Linux x86_64

Comment: Try to use the inspect element feature in Firefox and see if the CSS rule is applied for your visited link.

Comment: In this case, make sure your CSS file is included properly. Take a look at this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adLqaY Click on the link, and then go back. You'll see the color being red.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<a class=".extern" href="http://etc.etc.etc">link</a>
```

to

```
<a class="extern" href="http://etc.etc.etc">link</a>
```

and

```
<style>
    a.extern {
        padding-right:1.3em;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: scroll;
        background-position: right center;
        background-clip: border-box;
        background-origin: padding-box;
        background-size: 0.7em 0.7em;
        background-image: url("img/link.png");
    }

    a:visited:extern {
        background-image:url("img/link-visited.png");
    }

    a.extern:visited {
        background-image:url("img/link-visited.png");
    }
</style>
```

block with code below do not needed

```
a:visited:extern {
    background-image:url("img/link-visited.png");
}
```

Comment: sorry it was a typo when asking the question: the actual code doesn't has the `.` in front of the class name

Comment: css selectors :visited, :hover, etc always had to be in the end (just before { )