# CSS: conflict between -webkit-filter and filter

Tags: css, filter, webkit, visited

I have a navigation bar which uses images as links, like this:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#link">
        <img src="img/link.png">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

To create a glow around an unvisited link, I have the following CSS:

```
nav a img {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 8px #fff);
  -o-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 8px #fff);
  -ms-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 8px #fff);
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 8px #fff);
}

nav a:visited img {
  -webkit-filter: none;
  -o-filter: none;
  -ms-filter: none;
  filter: none;
}
```

In Chrome, the `nav a img` rule applies `-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 8px #fff);` and the `nav a:visited img` rule applies `filter: none;`, with the result that the glow remains even after the link has been visited.

[image: filter & -webkit-filter conflict]

Is there anything I can do about this?

On Firefox, the `nav a:visited img` rule is not acknowledged at all. Presumably this is due to [privacy concerns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector).

Is there a way to get an unvisited link image to glow, and a visited link image to not glow?

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827812/styling-visited-links-belonging-to-a-class?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 1):

The only properties of the :visited element that can be changed are:

color

background-color

border-color (and its sub-properties)

outline-color

The color parts of the fill and stroke properties

Comment: can you had some explanations ? ;)